# CodeIgniter will not send email using email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

When I use the PHP mail command emails are sent correctly (User web2 in Current Sessions in the screenshot), however they are not sent when using the CodeIgniter Email Library (User [null] in Current Sessions in the screenshot). Please could someone help with this issue, I have provided as much information as I can below, thanks.

application/config/email.php

```
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'Administrator';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'xxx';
$config['smtp_port']    = '25';
$config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
```

application/model/master.php

```
$site_config = $this->site_config();
// $this->load->library('email');
// $this->email->from($site_config['email_from'], $site_config['name']);
// $this->email->to($site_config['email_to']);
// $this->email->subject($subject);
// $this->email->message($html);
// if ($text==''){
//  $text = $html;
// }
// $this->email->set_alt_message($text);
$headers = 'From: '.$site_config['email_from'] . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$site_config['email_from'] . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (mail($site_config['email_to'], $subject, $text,$headers)){
// if ($this->email->send()){
    return 1;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

php.ini

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
```

IIS SMTP

```
Relay Restrictions
Only the list below
Granted 127.0.0.1
Granted localhost
Granted servername
[x] Allow all computers which successfully authenticate to rellay, regardless of the list above.

Outbound Security
Basic authentication
User name: xxx
Password: xxx

Advanced Delivery
Smart host: mail.external_host.com
```

[image: SMTP Current Sessions]

C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1

CodeIgniter (not working - terminated active connection manually)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-04-15 12:32:21
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-sitename s-computername s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) 
2014-04-15 12:32:21 127.0.0.1 - SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - - 240 21500 159 4 21500 SMTP - - - -
```

PHP Mail (working)

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2014-04-15 12:31:06
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-sitename s-computername s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query sc-status sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken cs-version cs-host cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) 
2014-04-15 12:31:06 127.0.0.1 web2 SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 HELO - +web2 250 0 28 9 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 127.0.0.1 web2 SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 MAIL - +FROM:<from@address_removed.com> 250 0 45 32 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 127.0.0.1 web2 SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 RCPT - +TO:<to@address_removed.com> 250 0 41 38 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 127.0.0.1 web2 SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 DATA - <WEB2FRaqbC8wSA1XvpF0000000b@web2> 250 0 117 663 31 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 127.0.0.1 web2 SMTPSVC1 WEB2 127.0.0.1 0 QUIT - web2 240 31 53 4 0 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 220+mail.external_host.com+ESMTP+Sendmail+8.14.2/8.14.2/;+Tue,+15+Apr+2014+13:31:13++0100+(BST) 0 0 90 0 47 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 EHLO - web2 0 0 4 0 47 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 250-mail.external_host.com+Hello+local.internal_host+[x.x.x.x]+(may+be+forged),+pleased+to+meet+you 0 0 112 0 78 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 AUTH - - 0 0 4 0 78 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 334+UGFzc3dvcmQ6 0 0 16 0 110 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 235+2.0.0+OK+Authenticated 0 0 26 0 141 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 MAIL - FROM:<from@address_removed.com>+SIZE=944 0 0 4 0 141 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 250+2.1.0+<from@address_removed.com>...+Sender+ok 0 0 45 0 157 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 RCPT - TO:<to@address_removed.com> 0 0 4 0 157 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 250+2.1.5+<to@address_removed.com>...+Recipient+ok 0 0 56 0 188 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 DATA - - 0 0 4 0 188 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 354+Enter+mail,+end+with+"."+on+a+line+by+itself 0 0 48 0 219 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 250+2.0.0+s3FCVDTZ085408+Message+accepted+for+delivery 0 0 54 0 547 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionCommand SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 QUIT - - 0 0 4 0 547 SMTP - - - -
2014-04-15 12:31:06 y.y.y.y OutboundConnectionResponse SMTPSVC1 WEB2 - 25 - - 221+2.0.0+mail.external_host.com+closing+connection 0 0 46 0 578 SMTP - - - -
```

print_debugger (when connection terminated manually)

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 39 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 890 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1816
y220 web2 Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 6.0.3790.3959 ready at Tue, 15 Apr 2014 14:08:56 +0100

hello: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 14:08:56 +0100 From: "From_Name_Here" Return-Path: To: to@address_removed.com Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Contact_Form?= Reply-To: "noreply@address_removed.com" X-Sender: noreply@address_removed.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <534d2f68ddae0@address_removed.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit This is a message --B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable This is a message --B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0--
Unable to send data: .

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 14:08:56 +0100
From: "From_Name_Here" 
Return-Path: 
To: to@address_removed.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?CLA_Contact_Form_(Brochure_Request)?=
Reply-To: "noreply@address_removed.com" 
X-Sender: noreply@address_removed.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <534d2f68ddae0@address_removed.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a message


--B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is a message

--B_ALT_534d2f68ddae0--
```

**EDIT :** I can confirm that the CodeIgniter email library works when connecting to an external smart host directly, however when connecting to the local IIS SMTP it is unable to connect successfully to relay. I have no idea why this would be as it is only a very basic set up with the minimal changes noted above.

**Fixed :** Changing the protocol to 'mail' the system is able to connect to the IIS SMTP local server and successfully relays the email through the smart host.

```
$config['protocol']     = 'mail';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_port']    = '25';
$config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are still using the mail() function despite going through the process of setting all the codeigniter config? I always use codeigniters built in email class for this sort of thing: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: I left the php mail code uncommented as that was the code that I last tested that worked. When using CodeIgniter (the commented code) it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use `$this->email->print_debugger()` to see possible error messages.

Comment: @Narf: If I don't specify an SMTP hostname I can get the print_debugger to display an error. Otherwise the code just hangs, the email library seems to create a connection but then is unable to successfully send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.

```
$this->load->library('email');
    $confing =array(
    'protocol'=>'smtp',
    'smtp_host'=>"smtp.gmail.com",
    'smtp_port'=>465,
    'smtp_user'=>"sender@gmail.com",
    'smtp_pass'=>"sender Password",
    'smtp_crypto'=>'ssl',              
    'mailtype'=>'html'  
    );
    $this->email->initialize($confing);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('sender@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to(receiver@gmail.com );
    $this->email->subject('You Subject');
    $this->email->message($message);

        if(!$this->email->send()) {
                        echo json_encode(1);
        }
```